# Creating Flow Chart with Tikz Picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create a simple image to demonstrate limits with a cat jumping towards a treat (the fish). I want the cat to be node 1 with L node 2 in the middle and the fish node 3. This is what I have so far but I can't figure out how to make node 2 to be in the middle (at the top of the curve). I also don't want a line between nodes 1 and 3. I apologize if I'm not making any sense, any help is appreciated!

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',auto,node distance=2in,
  thick,main node/.style={circle,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]
\node[main node] (1) {\Cat};
\node[main node] (2) {L};
\node[main node] (3) [right of=1] {\bcpoisson};

\draw [->] (1) -- (2)(1.north) to [out=150,in=30] (2.north);
\draw [->] (3) -- (2)(3.north) to [out=150,in=30] (2.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please convert your code snipped to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending eith `\end{document}`. In preamble of document add all your new commands and packages/libraries, whit are necessary for document compilation.

Comment: Your description is not very clear. Can you explain what you like with hand drawn sketch? Also search on this site for similar diagrams (automaton rather than flow chart) also look in http://www.texample.net/ where is lot of examples of similar images.  Many example are in TikZ & PGF manual too (it is part of TikZ installation).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols,bclogo}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
  [action/.style={font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries},
   actor/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=2em},
   >=stealth,
   thick
  ]
  \node[actor] (cat) {\Cat};
  \node[actor] (fish) [right=2cm of cat] {\bcpoisson};
  \draw[->] (cat) edge[bend left] node[above,action]{L} (fish);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```